# My insert statement (php to mysql) fails to use my variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, insert

It must be the simplest error, but I dont see nor find it.

I fill a variable `$aa_minerid` with value 7.
I use this variable in a insert.
The insert always inserts a 0 (zero) in the database never a 7

The field i put it in is a `smallint(6)`
I tried

```
VALUES ('$aa_productid')
VALUES ($aa_productid)
VALUES ("$aa_productid")
VALUES ('{$aa_productid}')
VALUES ("{$aa_productid}")
```

and all with use of ` aswell
into script placed hereafter.

If I put there : `VALUES ( 7 )`
It does work perfect.

So what do I do wrong in this script?
BTW the echo at the end DOES show the right value of the variable $aa_productid

```
<?php

/* This php script should transfer data from the aa to the sql database */

// Info coming from aa

$aa_productid = 7 ;

include ("dogs.inc");

$cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbname);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `Price` WHERE '
        . ' `Time_Stamp`=(select max(`Time_Stamp`) from `Price` where `Product_ID` = \'1\')';

$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or
                die("Couldn't execute select query");

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$aa_price=$row[3]   ;   

$aa_value = $aa_price * $aa_amount;

// Info ready to go to database

$sqlinsert = 'INSERT INTO Mining (Product_ID)'
      . ' VALUES ( $aa_productid )' ;

echo $aa_productid;
```

Comment: You DID remember to run mysqli_query with $sqlinsert at the end, right?

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes don't do variable expansion in PHP.  But I would recommend you use prepared statements, such as:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('INSERT INTO Mining (Product_ID) VALUES ( ? )');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $aa_productid);
$stmt->execute();
```

See the documentation at [prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

This will protect you from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`'.$aa_productid.'`
or 
`".$aa_productid."`

Depending on the type of apostrophe used to beging the string, use the same one.

Also, if You are using `"`, then You should be able to Just do

`$insert="INSERT INTO $tablename;";`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I have done any PHP but..

I think you need to have smartquotes turned on

Try this instead:

```
$sqlinsert = 'INSERT INTO Mining (Product_ID)'
  . ' VALUES ('. $aa_productid .' )' ;
```

concatenate the variable into the query.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using variables within quotes, you must use the double-quote if you want PHP to parse variables within it.  So, this would work:

```
$sqlinsert = 'INSERT INTO Mining (Product_ID) VALUES ('.$aa_productid.')';
```

Or this would:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO Mining (Product_ID) VALUES ($aa_productid)";
```

Comment: mmmmm i was so concentrated on the quotes around the variable and never tried to change the single and doubles around the whole statement :) And it did the trick. You guys are great!!

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer... any of them will do as they're all correct.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

$query = "SELECT * FROM Price WHERE Time_Stamp=(select max(Time_Stamp) from Price where Product_ID = "1")";

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO Mining (Product_ID) VALUES ( '$aa_productid' )" ;

Also, its always a good idea to escape the strings before entering them in the db.

Answer (score -1):

Try this syntax instead:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO Mining (Product_ID) VALUES ("' . $aa_productid . '")";
```

no need to concatenate the two parts of the insert. Also double quoting the variable seems to avoid problems.

Comment: Don't you have a problem with the `'` and `"` at the end ?

Comment: The quoting here is rather screwed up.  The single quotes shouldn't be where you have them.